# Apache url rewrite and image rename

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a PHP website with image names like 12345.jpg but the client wants images with name like mywebsite_12345.jpg

instead rename all images and modify upload script is it possible to use Apache url rewrite to find the correct image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have this rewrite rule in your `/imagesup/products/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /imagesup/products/ 

RewriteRule ^mywebsite_(.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff))$ $1 [L,NC]
```

Then you can include image in your pages with `src` as `/mywebsite_12345.jpg`

Comment: this will effect all images? because i need to do it only on images that are inside a specific directory ( that are dynamically uploaded ) like /imagesup/products/ or should i add .htaccess only inside that directory? thanks

Comment: Yes if you want to affect only a certain directory then check my updated rule.